# Is it possible to configure docker-nvidia for use with tensorflow-serving while hosting the docker virtual machine on Windows?

Tags: linux, windows, docker, tensorflow-serving

I have noticed while looking at [tensorflow serving's](https://www.tensorflow.org/serving/docker) guide for setting up tf serving with GPU support that it involves using [nvidia's docker](https://github.com/NVIDIA/nvidia-docker#quick-start) which is currently only available for Linux based systems. Since the docker tf serving container that I am using currently using is a linux machine itself, is it possible to configure nvidia-docker within the tfserving container so I can use my GPU's for model inference while running Docker on a host machine that runs Windows? Or is it a case where I need my host machine to be running Linux?

I'm under the impression that I can't run a docker instance from within a Linux virtual machine itself due to the virtualization requirements so I was wondering if there is a workaround by extending docker itself in some capacity.

Thanks in advance, I couldn't find any resources that go into detail about this in my thorough search of the problem and am relatively new to using Docker & tensorflow serving.

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe NVIDIA has any [intention](https://github.com/NVIDIA/nvidia-docker/wiki/Frequently-Asked-Questions#is-microsoft-windows-supported) on creating `nvidia-docker` for Windows, or at least not in the foreseeable future, since it would require creating Windows containers that would **directly** use host drivers. What I mean by that is that you won't be able to access the GPUs from a linux environment via a Windows host.

Besides, I think docker as a platform works best on Linux, especially when it comes to production, assuming that's what you are after. All in all, my advice would be sticking to battle-tested setups like `nvidia-docker` + TF Serving on Linux. You have a community of people that have done it before you, hence troubleshooting and solving issues is easier.